# Does anyone know what the function "U" represents here?

Tags: probability, functions

I was reading this article here : https://cnx.org/contents/JhSvg22o@5/Coxian-Distributions . This article makes several mentions about some function "u(t)", but there does not seem to be any direct mention as to what this function "u(t)" represents. For example:

[image]

"F*(t)  is the original distribution function, and F(t) is the approximation. If we define bi=ai−ai−1 and define a0=0, then we can write F(t) as
F(t)=b1u(t−t1)+b2u(t−t2)+…+bnu(t−tn)
where n is the number of steps and an=1. We can improve the approximation by increasing the number of steps and decreasing their heights."

- Can someone please help me understand what the function "u(t)" represents? Is this a standard way to denote some specific function?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably it's the Heaviside step function.

Comment: @ Dan: thank you for this comment! Just a question - how did you come to this conclusion? Thank you so much!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion based on past experience with the notation, and the graph of the approximation in Figure $1$ of the source material

Comment: @ Eevee Trainer: Thank you so much! Btw - Flareon, Jolteon or Vaporeon: which do you choose? :)